# How to properly reference to 2D arrays?

Tags: c++, reference, multidimensional-array, assign

I built an alternating digital tree algorithm in MATLAB but since it was too slow I am rewriting the program in C++.

At a certain stage a choice has to be made to search which tree. Depending on three values, x, y, and z, one out of three trees (stored as 2D arrays) has to be searched. Is there a way to refer to a 2D array so that it can be used in the search function later on?

Pseudo-code example:

```
double nodes1[12567][17];
double nodes2[8467][17];
double nodes3[11245][17];

fillMatrices(nodes1,nodes2,nodes3); // Here the matrices are filled with numbers from txt files.

if(condition1) // Based on x,y,z
{
    nodes=nodes1;
}
elseif(condition2) // Based on x,y,z
{
    nodes=nodes2;
}
else
{
    nodes=nodes3;
}

searchTree(nodes,x,y,z); // Function call with variable 2d array nodes
```

I hope the question is somewhat clear. I am fairly new to C++ and yes I do have some trouble to stop thinking in terms of matrices because of MATLAB ;)

I tried possibilities like:

```
double nodes[][] = nodes1[][];
double * nodes[] = nodes1[][17];
double nodes = &nodes1;
```

I am aware that arrays are passed by reference-ish when passed to a function but I just can't grasp how a 2D array works. Hope you can help me!

Regards,

Ernst Jan

Comment: use `std::vector` and forget about raw arrays

Comment: @TonyTheLion I thought vectors were meant for easy memory management and seemed slower than the standard arrays. Elements in those 2d arrays have to be accessed billions of times, is there any major performance loss when using vectors?

Comment: @EJG89: No, there is no loss at all. Why would there be? Did you ever profile it?

Comment: @DeadMG I only profiled it in MATLAB where the searchTree function was called 50k per particle. Bearing in mind that the goal is to track a million particles (on a cluster luckily) performance is of some concern.

EDIT: ah, I see you don't have to copy the vector every call but you can just reference to it saving overhead?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it if you include the size of the second array dimension in your parameter list, i.e.:

```
double nodes1[12567][17];
double nodes2[8467][17];
double nodes3[11245][17];

// note the array size declaration here:
void doSomething(double nodes[][17])
{
    //... access array "nodes" normally in here
}

int main()
{
    doSomething(nodes1);
    doSomething(nodes2);
    doSomething(nodes3);
}
```

This is only possible because the second dimension is the same size in each case. That gives the compiler enough information to know how to offset from one element to the next.

If the second dimension needs to vary as well, I'd recommend looking at the STL vector. You can nest one vector inside another quite easily.

Comment: I was indeed wondering whether this was possible but I tried it and indeed there is no problem at all! I just figured it out myself but I do think your solution fits this problem best.

Since the arrays are only accessed by indices stored inside themselves (search trees containing children) the information about the varying dimension is already implicitly stored and passed to the function.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use `double *` to reference those arrays. But with `double *`, you cannot use `[][]` to retrieve array element. Luckily, the second dimension of those arrays are all 17, so you can reference elements as `nodes[x * 17 + y]`.

Comment: @Even Li So my array is two dimensional but when referring to it using a pointer it degenerates to an array of pointers to doubles still structured so you can access the elements by their linear indices instead of their x,y indices?

Comment: In c, no matter what dimensional of an array, it's just a block of linear memory.